# Please I have been trying to deploy my congifmap.yaml file and asw-secret.yaml file and I keep getting some errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Each time I deploy the asw-secret.yaml file for my kubernetes cluster, I get this error: "error: resource mapping not found for name: "aws-secrets" namespace: "" from "aws-secret.yaml": no matches for kind "Secrets" in version "v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first"
I have installed the CRDs based on the instructions on AWS and it's still the same. This is my yaml file:

```html
 apiVersion: v1
kind: Secrets
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws                               
  parameters:
type: Opaque
data:
  Credentials: W2RlZmF1bHRdCmF3c19hY2Nlc3Nfa2V5X2lkID0gQUtJQTJCQzRZUzI2WlhDUTVDVE4K
```

And for the configmap, I keep getting the following error: "Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "env-configmap.yaml": configmap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: no kind "configmap" is registered for version "v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:30"

Please I need help!

Comment: The type is `Secret`, not `Secrets`. I imagine that for the configmap, it is a similar typo.

Answer (score 0):

remove the "provider" and "parameter" and then again the name should be aws-secret, do these and run kubectl apply -f to your file again.